# DevExpress Winforms(Net Framework) Template Gallery is not available

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

My first project working fine
[image]

But in second project suddenly disappeared project template items. I need UserControl item.
[image]

I check structure of  .csproj files in both project, but i can't find difference.
Please help, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the referenced Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client library in the first project. After removing this library the problem is resolved.